# How to set PreferenceScreen into other layout in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want use `PreferenceScreen` in my application, and create XML layout for this activity in **res/xml/setting_preference.xml**. but this XML layout is very simple, i want use this layout in another layout.
For example : i want use **setting_preference.xml** into **setting_activity.xml** , setting_activity.xml path is **res/layout/setting_activity.xml**.

How can i it?
**setting_preference XML code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="setting_title_title_category"
        android:title="Title options">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:id="@+id/setting_title_show_id"
        android:key="setting_title_show"
        android:title="Show Main Title"
        android:summary="Show/hide MainPage title"
        android:checked="true"/>

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="setting_title_text"
        android:title="Set Main Title"
        android:summary="Change MainPage title"
        android:dialogTitle="Change Title"
        android:dialogMessage="Change title please..."/>

    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="setting_title_font_category"
        android:title="Font options">

        <ListPreference
            android:key="setting_title_font_color"
            android:title="Title font colors"
            android:summary="Change title font colors"
            android:entries="@array/colors"
            android:entryValues="@array/colors"
            android:dialogTitle="Change font color" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

    <RingtonePreference
        android:title="tes"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

**setting_activity XML code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.tellfa.nikandroid.mytestdbproject.SettingPage">

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Setting Page code:**

```
public class SettingPage extends PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if (key.equals("setting_title_font_color")) {
            // get preference by key
            Preference pref = findPreference(key);
            // do your stuff here
        }

        if (key.equals("setting_title_show")){

            Preference pref = findPreference(key);
        }
    }

    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.setting_prefrences);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a frameLayout where you want to load your xml preference file in the layout xml file and implement PreferenceFragment in that activity.

Comment: [Follow this](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/maester-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/blendedlabs/maester/SettingsActivity.java) You can extend Activity or AppCompatActivity instead of PreferenceActivity

Comment: Unfortunately not helpful to me

Comment: What would be the point of this? If you want an activity containing a preference fragment, then you don't need a layout for that activity. You only need to open the activity and in onCreate attach the preference fragment. For this you don't need layout for activity at all. The other solution would be to create an activity layout with <fragment> tag pointing to the preference fragment. If you could better explain what the end results would be, maybe we can help you better.